# In how many ways can two committees be selected if there is no overlap between committees?

Tags: combinatorics

[The questions i need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jchS.png)

Hello I have added my questions in the image, I couldn't solve from 1 to 3 , I have tried in question 1 something but im not sure if its correct

---

Edit: Here is the first question from the picture:

1.1 In a club with $20$ members how many ways are there to choose two comittees, $3$ and $4$ members respectively. And no-one in the same comittee.

1.2.In a club with $20$ members, how many way are there to choose a comittee  of $7$ members and a subcomittee of $3$ members from the larger comittee.

Comment: Your three questions have parts, so you are actually asking six questions, which is too broad for this forum.  Please pick a particular question that is giving you difficulty, explain what you have attempted, and where you are stuck.

Comment: would you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1.1 We start with $20$ members and we have to choose $4$ members for the first comittee. These can be done in $\binom{20}{4}$ different ways. For the second comittee, with $3$ members in, we cannot choose from them who are alredy in the first comitte which leaves us with $\binom{20-4}{3}=\binom{16}{3}$. Finally you can use the Rule of Products.

1.2 First you choose $7$ from all of the members and then we choose $3$ out of this $7$, right? The structure is the same as above.

Hope this helps :)